# NodeJS - How to check if Gzip Compression is working?

Tags: node.js, compression

Is there a way to check if the response is being compressed? I'm using NodeJS Zlib module in my compression.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as decompressing the result and comparing the data with the original one.

```
const input = '.................................';
const zlib = require('zlib');

zlib.deflate(input, (err, buffer) => {
    if (!err) {
        zlib.unzip(buffer, (err, _buffer) => {
            if (!err) {
                // Is that equal?
                console.log(input === _buffer.toString());
            } else {
                // handle error
            }
        });
    } else {
        // handle error
    }
});
```

Also, [constants](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_constants) are an important source of what's going on behind.

The previous example is a slight modification of the official documentation [given](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_examples)

Source: Same experience in Java has been really traumatic, as I've checked that very little sources of information tend to get bigger in the compressed form. I advice you to compress information only –and just only– if it's really big (>1MB).